# CodeIgniter Rest-Api : Multiple Like Query Searching

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I'm want build some **multiple Searching** function in rest-api using Codeigniter, but the problem data not show when I'm test in **Postman** .

I'm using this code to build Searching function :

Result I want 1 :

```
Select * from Mahasiswa where nrp=$keyword OR nama=$keyword
```

Result I want 2 :

```
Select * from Mahasiswa where nrp like $keyword OR nama like $keyword
```

**Controller**:

```
public function search_get()
{
    $keyword = $this->get('nrp');
    $keyword = $this->get('nama');
    $msgEmpty = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Data Not Found'];
    if ($keyword === null) {
        $mahasiswa =  $this->mahasiswa->showMahasiswa();
    } else {
        $mahasiswa = $this->mahasiswa->showMahasiswa($keyword);
    }
    if ($mahasiswa) {
        $this->set_response([
            'status' => true,
            'data' => $mahasiswa,
        ], 200);
    } else {
        $this->set_response($msgEmpty, 404);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function showMahasiswa($keyword = null)
{
    if ($keyword === null) {
        return $this->db->get('mahasiswa')->result_array();
    } else {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('mahasiswa');
        if($keyword){
            $this->db->or_like('nrp',$keyword);
        }
        if($keyword){
            $this->db->or_like('nama',$keyword);
        }
        $this->db->get();
        // return $this->db->get_where('mahasiswa', ['id' => $id])->result_array();
    }
}
```

I've already used multiple where condition like this:

Example 1 :

```
public function showMahasiswa($keyword = null)
{
    if ($keyword === null) {
        return $this->db->get('mahasiswa')->result_array();
    } else {
        $where  = "nrp=$keyword OR nama=$keyword";
        return $this->db->get_where('mahasiswa', $where)->result_array();


        // return $this->db->get_where('mahasiswa', ['id' => $id])->result_array();
    }
}
```

Example 2 :

```
public function showMahasiswa($keyword = null)
{
    if ($keyword === null) {
        return $this->db->get('mahasiswa')->result_array();
    } else {
        $multipleKeyword =['nrp'=> $keyword,'nama'=> $keyword];
        $this->db->where($multipleKeyword);
        $this->db->get('mahasiswa')->result_array();


        // return $this->db->get_where('mahasiswa', ['id' => $id])->result_array();
    }
}
```

But all nothing work.

Can you help me with this case ? And Suggest me what the best query for searching in rest-api using CodeIgniter

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this query :

```sql
Select * from Mahasiswa where nrp=$keyword OR nama=$keyword
```

You could use this :

```php
public function showMahasiswa($keyword = null)
{
    if ($keyword === null) {
        return $this->db->get('mahasiswa')->result_array();
    } else {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('mahasiswa');
        if ($keyword) {
            $this->db->or_where('nrp', $keyword);
            $this->db->or_where('nama', $keyword);
        }
        $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

To get this query :

```sql
Select * from Mahasiswa where nrp like $keyword OR nama like $keyword
```

You could use this :

```php
public function showMahasiswa($keyword = null)
{
    if ($keyword === null) {
        return $this->db->get('mahasiswa')->result_array();
    } else {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('mahasiswa');
        if($keyword){
            $this->db->or_like('nrp',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('nama',$keyword);
        }
        $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

And you have invalid `get` method.

This :

```php
$keyword = $this->get('nrp');
$keyword2 = $this->get('nama');
```

Should be :

```php
$keyword = $this->input->get('nrp');
$keyword2 = $this->input->get('nama');
```

Comment: Sorry can i make little change question ? because i'm mistake something

Comment: Sure you can ;)

Comment: I want search just with 1 parameter ```$keyword``` but with multiple column in table database(etc, **nama** and **nrp**
#sorry for my last mistake stupid question

Comment: well you have a valid codes, so what is your question then? that codes is going to search using one keyword

Comment: Oke, I get it ! . Thanks .